# Ubuntu 16.04 installation frozen (taking too long)

Tags: usb, 16.04

So im installing Ubuntu right now and it's frozen at one point.It's just stops there and also it takes longer than **4-5 hours** to install which is pretty weird..Can someone help?

Comment: Can you take a picture of your screen? That would help us see where it is stuck at.

Comment: Is there a way to screenshot?

Comment: Maybe use your phone?

Comment: Im not sure if I can..

Comment: I just replicated this on a fresh install of Ubuntu Studio 16.04 (xenial). You can see the last few lines of terminal output on [this screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/UbQu1)

Comment: This appears to be related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1584030

Comment: Check your ISO. Also provide details about architecture of processor.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like this maybe a older machine your using and maybe you should try a lighter version of Ubuntu like **[Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) or [Kubuntu](http://kubuntu.org/)** they require less resources to run on older computers

With out knowing what the specs are I'm assuming it's an older computer with that said, some older machines may not even be able to install a distribution like 16.04, I have older machines also and when I try installing Ubuntu 16.04 it just hanged at one point and would not install.

I had to switch to a lighter version of Linux like **Linux light** or **Lubuntu** and was able to complete my installation. It's a suggestion and be of use

Comment: That shouldn't have such a large effect on how long Ubuntu takes to install.